# Ставится ли запятая? "Я думала(,) только из-за внешности..."

Tags: пунктуация

Я думала(,) (осуждаете ее) только из-за внешности.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится.

Предложение сложноподчинённое, две основы:

(Я) думала; (вы) осуждаете.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ставится:

**Я думала,  только из-за внешности.**

Грамматику удобно представить следующим образом: Это простое неполное предложение, осложненное вводным предложением "я думала".